Is it proper procedure to merge several answers into mine?
With regards to question Unidenitified LEGO set, I wonder if it is proper custom to take parts of other answers and merge them into the most comprehensive one to create one, all-encompassing answer? 
I don't want to generate the impression that I am stealing answers from others to boost my own answer. User @shea just added another answer with a component that is new info. Since my answer was the first and is the most comprehensive at this point, is it okay to add the component of @shea's question into mine?

Ideally, we'd like to have a "definitive" answer to a question - this is exactly what Community Wiki was originally designed for - multiple people working on a single answer - you can convert your answer into a Community Wiki (which won't affect any other answers to the question) as you edit it - see for example my answer to What is the largest single LEGO piece.
As the OP can only accept one answer, it's not unreasonable for some dedicated user to combine other answers into their own to form a whole answer - however it is only polite in that case to note that inspiration/details came from the other answers and up-vote them (there's even a badge for that).
